# Iterate through association rules using the header of an itemset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-mining, apriori

I have a data frame of inputs which look like this

[image]

I generate association rules using pandas

```
frequent_itemsets = apriori(df, min_support=0.2, use_colnames=True)
rules = association_rules(frequent_itemsets, metric= "confidence", min_threshold = 0.6 )
```

My output only generates rules values of each itemset without labeling the header. It looks something like below. My questions are
1-  I want to label the antecedent and consequents with their header name (Age, AL, Sex,...etc) because I can't differentiate between all the output numbers. Example:

```
Age = 20, Smoke = n   => Chol = y
```

2- If I have the previous rule and I want to iterate on all rules in my output to do some calculations, how can I do this given the information in my output

[image]

Comment: As a *set* is non-positional, you already lost the information in which column you had a y or n...

Comment: What is the suggested solution? I have thought about this solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902140/how-to-add-a-header-name-next-to-its-cell-value-in-python?noredirect=1#comment96574208_54902140

Comment: I'm not quite sure this is an ideal solution tho

Comment: Why didn't you *try*?

Comment: I will! It's just I'm new to it and wondering if there is a better idea to solve it rather than rewrite the whole dataframe as I will be having multiple of them with more data

Comment: `use_colnames=False` certainly is more elegant, but I'm not sure it will help. This also seems to be a quite poor implementation (actually *not* of the real Apriori algorithm, but one that scales much worse). So I'd first switch to the much better pyFIM version.