# How to add a header name next to its cell value in python

Tags: python, pandas, cell

I have this table as an input and I would like to add the name of the header to its corresponding cells before converting it to a dataframe

[image]

I am generating association rules after converting the table to a dataframe and each rule is not clear if it belongs to which antecedent/consequent.

Example for the first column of my desired table:

```
Age
Age = 45
Age = 30 
Age = 45
Age = 80
```

.
.
and so on for the rest of the columns. What is the best way to access each column and rewrite them? And is there a better solution to reference my values after generating association rules other than adding the name of the header to each cell?

Comment: It does feel completely obsolete adding the header name to each cell...  Could you expand on the reason you want to do this or add an example for context?

Comment: I agree. The reason I want is to label the antecedent and consequent values( which are only numbers here) after generating association rules. Further explanation here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54900630/iterate-through-association-rules-using-the-header-of-an-itemset

Comment: I other words, I would like to index the cells with the header name

Comment: But you can do this, `df['Age']` gives you the whole column and then you can just reference the numerical index? Maybe I am misunderstanding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to add the column names to all cells:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age':[1,2],'sex':['M','F']})
df = df.applymap(str)

for c in df.columns:
    df[c] = df[c].apply(lambda s: "{} = {}".format(c,s))
```

This yields:

```
    age     sex
0   age = 1 sex = M
1   age = 2 sex = F
```

Comment: What if I'm reading from CSV file. Is there a way to map the string to its columns?